# why my jbdc database funtion cant read foward slash

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a function that reads a primary key from my database and I can't read foward slash for some reason.

```
host: jdbc:postgresql://databaseurl
    dbname: databasename
    dbuser: databaseuser
    dbpass: databasepass
```

This is my input, and this is my function for that input

```
public static String pkDatabase(String host, String dbname, String dbuser, String dbpass, String table)
            throws IOException, SQLException {

        String url = host + "//" + dbname;
        String user = dbuser;
        String password = dbpass;

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

        ResultSet rs1 = meta.getTables(null, null, table, new String[] { table });
        rs1 = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, table);

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            arr.add(rs1.getString(4));
        }

        String listString = "";

        for (String s : arr) {
            listString += s;
        }

        return listString;

    }
```

and this is my output

```
FATAL: database "/databasename" does not exist
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add to your post the parameters that you're sending to **pkDatabase(...)** ?

Comment: Villat i already am in the post , host: jdbc:postgresql://databaseurl,
    dbname: databasename,
    dbuser: databaseuser,
    dbpass: databasepass,
this one thanks

Comment: The URL your code generates is invalid, because the separator between host and database name should be a single `/`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at this line

```
    String url = host + "//" + dbname;
```

It should have only one forward slash

```
    String url = host + "/" + dbname;
```

Comment: if i do that, this is the outcome "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://databaseurldatabasename"

Comment: @ridwansyarifudin it means that your question **why my jbdc database funtion cant read foward slash** is solved. Your outcome is based on the MetaData algorithm that you wrote after connecting to the database. Please accept my answer if your connection is working :)

Comment: Could you add a log message or System.out.print(...) to see what's on **String url**?

Comment: URL
jdbc:postgresql://databaseurl/databasename
Oct 08, 2019 11:34:22 AM org.postgresql.Driver parseURL
WARNING: JDBC URL must contain a / at the end of the host or port: jdbc:postgresql://databaseurldatabasename

this is my error log sir

Comment: @ridwansyarifudin it's like you removed both slashes, did you preserve only one as I wrote? Is it a forward slash **/** ?

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://100.100.10.100:5000 , this is the databaseurl value sir

Comment: What happens if you write **String url = "jdbc:postgresql://100.100.10.100:5000/YOURDBNAMEHERE";** ? If that works, could you try to change your code to **String url = host + dbname;** and send the *host* in the parameter as _jdbc:postgresql://100.100.10.100:5000/_ ?

Comment: if i do that it works, but the requirement i want for host is to not type in the forward slash in end of host, i want only to put in "jdbc:postgresql://100.100.10.100:5000"

Comment: Your dbname is not using any special character, right? Please try with **String url = new StringBuilder().append(host).append("/").append(dbname).toString();**

Comment: thanks villat, its my faulth for not being thorough, ure right thanks